# multi cpu core gzip a big file

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, cpu-cores

How can I use all cpu cores in my server(has 4 cores) linux Debian over OpenVZ to **gzipping** faster **one big file**?

I am trying to use these commands but I can not put the pieces together

get number of cores

`CORES=$(grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo)`

this for split big file in more

`split -b100 file.big`

this for use gzip command with multiple core

`find /source -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P $CORES gzip --best`

I don't know if this is the best way for optimize gzip process of big files..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pigz`](http://zlib.net/pigz/), a parallel gzip implementation.

Unlike `parallel` with `gzip`, `pigz` produces a single gzip stream.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you think a single stream is advantageous please?

Comment: The gzip command-line utility will process concatenated gzip streams properly, but most other software will not.  Most other software will stop at the end of the first gzip stream, including just about every web browser asking for gzip content encoding.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - though if the files are big enough to warrant multi-core processing they are unlikely to be for web use.

Answer (score 2):

Try GNU Parallel

```
cat bigfile | parallel --pipe --recend '' -k gzip -9 >bigfile.gz
```

This will use all your cores to gzip in parallel.

By way of comparison, on my Mac running OSX Mavericks, and using a 6.4GB file on solid state disk, this command

```
time gzip -9 <bigger >/dev/null
```

takes 4 minutes 23s and uses 1-2 CPUs at around 50%.

Whereas the GNU Parallel version below

```
time cat bigger | parallel --pipe --recend '' -k gzip -9 >/dev/null
```

takes 1 minute 44 seconds and keeps all 8 cores 80+% busy. A very significant difference, with GNU Parallel running in under 40% of the time of the simplistic approach.

Comment: in my server(under OpenVZ) is not exists GNU parallel! but only parallel command of moreutils package!

Comment: `(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash` will install GNU Parallel in 10 seconds. With version 20140622 you can use --pipe-part which is more efficient if bigger.file is a file and not a pipe.