# Compressing huge file (~30 GB) in parallel?

Tags: .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, io, compression

So, first of all, I read file in chunks on 32MBs:

```
var inputFileReader = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var buffer = new byte[_32_MB];
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(fileURL, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream))
            {
                while (bufferedStream.Read(buffer, 0, _32_MB) != 0)
                {
                    // queue might be oversized:
                    // .Wait() suppose to guarantee it won't happen
                    _queue.Wait();
                    _queue.Push(buffer);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("File reading done.");
                _applicationIsRunning = false;
            }
        });
```

Then the other threads (which are not yet implemented) suppose to take those raw chanks of bytes and compress them using `MemoryStream`. I expect something like this to work with only correction that I'd like to reuse some number of threads rather than create a new one each time:

```
public static byte[] GZip(byte[] bytes)
    {
        byte[] res = { };

        var compressor = new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
            {
                gZipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                res = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        });
        compressor.Start();

        return res;
    }
```

---

**Question**: now it seems like my design is totally wrong: how can I maintain an order of chunks while writing them into an outfile (which obviously must take place sequentially). Seems like compressing is non-determenistic, and even if I would know the unique index of each chunk, it won't help a lot: a still don't know where it gonna be after compression.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can have a simple manager class with a method like `Register(int index, byte[] chunk)`, and each time it's called it adds the new chunk into an internal sorted list, after which it flushes any remembered chunks already in the list, in a loop, each time taking the chunk with the index of previous+1 and stopping if it's not yet in the list. However, by concatenating several gzip streams in one file you might end up with a [file you don't like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24396236/#comment37767963_24400910). Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38143922/11683.

Comment: You need one thread that does all the writing, and a list of compressed data chunks for it to pull from. That list would have sequence numbers, so the write thread can write them in order, and wait as needed for the next number in the sequence to show up.